# In applescript, how can I access the keyboard shortcut of a menu item?

Tags: macos, applescript, menuitem

I'm trying to figure out the keyboard shortcut (e.g., shift+cmd+S) of a given menu item in Applescript. The "Probe Menu Bar" script has helped me to access the menu items and even inspect their properties and such, but I've been unable to discover which of these will print out the keyboard shortcut.

The probe script is like this:

```
tell process "Finder"
get every menu bar
tell menu bar 1
get every menu bar item
get every menu of every menu bar item
get every menu item of every menu of every menu bar item
```

So I just need a way to print out / collect the shortcut from said "menu item" during this loop.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks the keyboard shortcut information is available as attributes of each menu bar item:

```
tell application "System Events"
    get name of menu item 2 of menu 3 of menu bar 1 of process "Finder"
        --> "New Folder"
    get every attribute of menu item 2 of menu 3 of menu bar 1 of process "Finder"
           --> {attribute "AXRole" of menu item "New Finder Window" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder", [...]
    get properties of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdChar" of [...]
        --> {value:"N", class:attribute, settable:false, name:"AXMenuItemCmdChar"}
    get properties of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdModifiers" of [...]
    --> {value:1, class:attribute, settable:false, name:"AXMenuItemCmdModifiers"}
```

There's some elaboration of the attributes and their values [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2004/Apr/msg00019.html) and detailed reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: P.S. It's considered good Stack Overflow etiquette to either mark an answer as accepted (so that the answerer gets reputation points) or leave a commment clarifying what you are looking for.

Comment: Oops - didn't see your comment until just now. Thanks for the answer!

I will work on my etiquette :-)

Comment: Your solution seems to only work with "CMD" shortcut. How can I detect what are the other key modifier like "Control" and "Options". I would like to detect for examples that in Mail, "Bcc Address Field" is Option+Cmd+B